# Sort object array by number value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array with this mock:

```
export class Task {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  state: number;
  priority: number;
  describtion: string;
}
```

This array is filled with multiple entries and each has a priority from 1-5.

**How can I sort this array by its priority (asc)?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
tasks.sort((currentValue: Task, nextValue: Task) => currentValue.priority - nextValue.priority);
```